# WPF Webbrowser handling TouchEvents for PDF-File

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, browser, touch-event

In my application i want to scroll via Touch-Event (Finger) in an implemented Webbrowser, which is displaying a pdf document.

The application is developed for a tabletop-application.

If i implement a TouchDown-method in my xaml nothing happens. So i think my Touch-Events are overwritten somewhere.

Any Idea?

Comment: Maxi, I am having the same problem and I guess there is not much hope at the moment. According to my research, this is due to the "Airspace Problem" (http://www.jonathanantoine.com/2011/09/24/wpf-4-5-%E2%80%93-part-8-no-more-airspace-problems-integrating-wpf-with-win32/), which MS declines to solve: http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2644120-bring-back-the-hwndhost-isredirected-and-compositi